# Application freezes after socket server starts listening for socket client connection python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Application hangs after starting up the server but the socket server was properly created. so whenever i execute a client the server response properly. Why does the application hangs? Here is the sample code

Start Button - Trigger Button

```
ui.button.clicked.connect(start_server) # Button to start the process
```

Server Socket, in here I created a thread for all the connected clients to the server then the server will broadcast it to clients

```
def start_server():
    host = "192.168.8.241"
    port = 1024
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print("Socket created")
    try:
        soc.bind((host, port))
    except:
        print("Bind failed. Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()
    soc.listen(5)
    print("Socket now listening")
    while True:
        connection, address = soc.accept()
        ip, port = soc.getsockname()

    print("Connected with " + str(ip) + ":" + str(port))

    try:
        Thread(target=client_thread, args=(connection, ip, port)).start()
    except:
        print("Thread did not start.")
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Client Thread

```
def client_thread(connection, ip, port, max_buffer_size = 5120):
    is_active = True

    while is_active:
        client_input = receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size)

        if "--QUIT--" in client_input:
            print("Client is requesting to quit")
            connection.close()
            print("Connection " + str(ip) + ":" + str(port) + " closed")
            is_active = False
        else:
            print("Processed result: {}".format(client_input))
            connection.sendall(client_input)

def receive_input(connection, max_buffer_size):
    client_input = connection.recv(max_buffer_size)
    client_input_size = sys.getsizeof(client_input)

    if client_input_size > max_buffer_size:
        print("The input size is greater than expected {}".format(client_input_size))

    decoded_input = client_input.decode("utf8").rstrip()  # decode and strip end of line
    result = process_input(decoded_input)

    return result

def process_input(input_str):
    print("Processing the input received from client")
    return "Hello " + str(input_str).upper()
```

Client

```
def main():
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "192.168.8.241"
    port = 1024
    print("client_soc", soc)

    try:
        soc.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print("Connection error")
        sys.exit()

    print("Enter 'quit' to exit")
    message = input(" -> ")

    while message != 'quit':
        soc.sendall(message.encode("utf8"))
        while True:
            data = soc.recv(1024)
            print("Received response:" + str(data))
            message = input(" -> ")


    soc.send(b'--quit--')
```

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(client_input)` is not the way to get the length of data.  That get's the length of the internal Python object used to store the data.  Use `len(client_input)`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen already solved it, thanks though. :)